# JavaFX How to set Tab on click action when tab is disabled?

Tags: tabs, javafx

Is it possible to set on click action when Tab is disabled? I would like to inform user to do some action before accessing this Tab

Comment: i think you can use pop up dialog for some user action.if user agree with that you can call action.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer, and it is pretty simple.

1. Create Label and add to it onClick event handler
2. Set use label as tab graphic

   **tab.setGraphic(label);**

Easy, and it's working just fine.